# Merging folders in Windows, changing file names

Tags: windows, windows-8, file-management

I am using Windows 8 and I was wondering if it's possible to merge folders that contain files with the same name, but instead of overwriting them, changing the name.

For example:

```
Folder A, with files 01, 02, and 03  
Folder B, with files 01, 02, and 03
```

I want the result to be

```
Folder C (or any name) with:
   Files 01(A01), 02(A02), 03(A03), 04(B01), 05(B02) and 06(B03)
```

All of these being the files the same that were in folders A and B, and also taking care that the order is the same.

Comment: Do you just want the files to be named `01`, `02`, `03`, ... (with the `A` files getting the lowest _n_ numbers) regardless of the original file names? Because it might be more useful in the long run to go with a `A-01`, `A-02`, `A-03`, `A-antelope`, `A-buffalo`, `A-cat`, `A-dog`, ..., `B-01`, ..., scheme.

Comment: I am not really interested in the file name as long as it keeps the order of the files in a lexicographic order and having the files that were originally in folder A before the files in folder B.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following script (batch file):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set counter=1000

set target=c

for %%S in (a b) do (
        for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir %%S /b/a-d/one') do (
                set /a counter=counter+1
                move %%S\"%%F" %target%\"%%~xF"
        )
)
```

Notes:

- `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` enables special handling of variables in loops.
- `for %%S in (a b) do …` executes the following group of statements
  once for each value in the parentheses, with `%%S` set to the value. 
  I chose the letter `S` for this because these are the **s**ource directories. 
  You can put as many source directories between the parentheses as you want.
- `for /f "delims=" %%F in ('…') do …` executes the following group of statements
  once for each line of output from the command in the `'…'` quotes,
  with `%%F` set to the line. 
  I chose the letter `F` for this because these are the **f**ile names.
- `dir %%S /b/a-d/one` gives a **b**are (no header, dates, sizes, etc.) listing
  of the files in the source directory `%%S`. 
  `/a-d` means list files only (no directories);
  `/one` means **o**rder (sort) the entries by **n**ame and **e**extension.
- `set /a counter=counter+1` is self-explanatory.
- So finally we execute a `move` command,
  moving the file (`%%F`) from the source directory (`%%S`) to the target directory.  
  `!counter:~1!` is a form of the
  `%variable:~start,length%` syntax,
  taking the substring of the `counter` variable from the second character
  (because the first character is #0) to the end. 
  So, if `counter` is stepping through the values 1001, 1002, 1003, …,
  then this substring is 001, 002, 003, etc. 
  If you are sure that you have fewer than 100 files,
  you can change the initialization of `counter` to 100. 
  And `%%~xF` is the extension of the `%%F` filename.

This moves all the files in the `a` and `b` directories. 
If you want to get everything in the `a` and `b` directory trees, change the inner loop to

```
        for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir %%S /b/a-d/one/s') do (
                set /a counter=counter+1
                move "%%F" %target%\"!counter:~1!%%~xF"
        )
```

- Adding `/s` to the `dir` command makes it recursive.
- While `dir directory_name /b` gives you just filenames,
  `dir directory_name /b/s` gives you full paths,
  so the `move` command doesn’t need to include the `%%S` source directory.

More notes:

- This will handle file names with spaces in them.
- This will handle directory names with spaces in them – just quote them:

  ```
  set target="c food"

  for %%S in ("a train" "b good") do (
                  ︙
  ```

Of course you should test this first with `move` changed to `echo move`.